Where does the command gpg pull the asc data?
I am running this script and I am having a problem understanding where is is pulling the data.
for %%f in (C:\data\out\*.txt) do (
    gpg --encrypt -r vendor.asc -o C:\data\out\%%~nf.pgp %%f

I did not create this script so I am not sure how or where it is pulling vendor.asc? any help would be appreciated.
